# Is there any way to get more than 60 results from Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

I can't figure out how to get more than 60 results from Google Places API.
Are there any workarounds, or is it actually impossible to get anything more than 60??

Comment: The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing) lists the limits, and nowhere does it state the limit is 60 results.  We can't answer your question with the lack of details.  Please edit your question and add in your code segment that demonstrates your problem, and then explain what results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#PlacesNearbySearchResponse-next_page_token) the max amount of results you can get is 60, please notice that the API returns a paginated response showing up to 20 results per page. It is impossible to get more than that since there is no option or parameter you can configure to set the amount of results yo want.